# kustomization: patch in multiple volumeMounts

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

I'm trying to patch in (patchJSON6922) multiple volumeMounts to a base kustomization.  However, when I patch in more than one volumeMounts I get errors. Here's my configuration:

kustomization.yaml

```
commonLabels:
  app: my-app

imageTags:
  - name: my-app
    newName: localhost/my-app
    newTag: latest

bases:
- app

patchesJson6902:
- target:
    group: apps
    version: v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-app
  path: create_volume_one.yaml
- target:
    group: apps
    version: v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: my-app
  path: create_volume_two.yaml
```

create_volume_one.yaml

```
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/volumeMounts
  value:
    name: volumeOne
    mountPath: /data/one
```

create_volume_two.yaml

```
- op: add
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/volumeMounts/-
  value:
    name: volumeTwo
    mountPath: /data/two
```

When I run said kustomization I get the following error:

```sh
$> kubectl kustomize .
Error: found conflict between different patches
&resource.Resource{Kunstructured:(*kunstruct.UnstructAdapter)(0xc000010058), options:(*types.GenArgs)(0xc00038eb00)} doesn't deep equal &resource.Resource{Kunstructured:(*kunstruct.UnstructAdapter)(0xc0000c6038), options:(*types.GenArgs)(0xc00038eb00)}


Examples:
  # Use the current working directory
  kubectl kustomize .

  # Use some shared configuration directory
  kubectl kustomize /home/configuration/production

  # Use a URL
  kubectl kustomize github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize.git/examples/helloWorld?ref=v1.0.6

Usage:
  kubectl kustomize <dir> [flags] [options]

Use "kubectl options" for a list of global command-line options (applies to all commands).

found conflict between different patches
&resource.Resource{Kunstructured:(*kunstruct.UnstructAdapter)(0xc000010058), options:(*types.GenArgs)(0xc00038eb00)} doesn't deep equal &resource.Resource{Kunstructured:(*kunstruct.UnstructAdapter)(0xc0000c6038), options:(*types.GenArgs)(0xc00038eb00)}
```

I tried various paths (with and without the `-` after `volumeMounts` but with no avail).

When I comment out the create_volume_two.yaml section everything works.  So I'm wondering what do I need to do to append to the `volumeMounts` properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the `kubectl` version of `kustomize` (2.0.3) is old and doesn't support appending to items.  Using the latest kustomize (3.1.0) fixed my issue.